# constructor for a class with template using iterators

Tags: c++

I have a Hashmap Class in the header

```
template <typename K, typename M, typename H = std::hash<K>>
class HashMap {
public: 
template <class Iterator>
    HashMap(const Iterator& begin, const Iterator& end);
};
```

How do I declare this in the cpp file?

I tried:

```
template <class <typename K, typename M, typename H> Iterator>
HashMap<K, M, H>::HashMap(const Iterator& begin, const Iterator& end)
```

It does not work. Thanks.

Comment: One note: if you put the definition of the constructor into a separate file (.cpp while the template class is defined in the .h file) you would experience problems with linking the instantiations.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, your caption is confusing. There are alternative solutions.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov  Sorry - my caption *is* the title of that other question.

Comment: The answer for this question might be useful: "Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file  And also this one: "Why the .cpp is not accessible by the compiler when instanciated a template class?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838845/why-the-cpp-is-not-accessible-by-the-compiler-when-instanciated-a-template-clas

Answer (score 4):

You need *separate* templates for the class and the constructor, like this:

```
template <typename K, typename M, typename H>
  template <class Iterator>
    HashMap<K,M,H>::HashMap(const Iterator& begin, const Iterator& end) {
 // ...
}
```

Note that the out of line definition of the constructor can't specify the default template parameters.

Also, your question says you want to put this in the `.cpp` file, but you shouldn't do that. Templates should always be in header files.

Comment: The default argument for template parameter (`= std::hash<K>`) is not needed.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Oops, in fact, it's not even allowed. Nice catch, thanks :)